# Error messages when running glmer in R

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I am attempting to run two similar generalized linear mixed models in R. Both models have the same input variables for predictors, covariates and random factors, however, response variables differ. Models require the `lme4` package. The issue I was having with the second model has been resolved by Ben Bolker.

In the first model, the response variable is biomass weight and `family = gaussian`.

```
 global.model <- lmer(ex.drywght ~ forestloss562*forestloss17*roaddenssec*nearestroadprim + 
                            elevation + soilPC1 + soilPC2 +
                            (1|block/fragment), 
                          data = RespPredComb, 
                          family = "gaussian") 

Predictors have the following units: 
    forestloss562 = %,
    forestloss17 = %, 
    roaddenssec = (km/km2) and
    nearestroadprim = (m).
```

Executing this model brings up the following warning messages:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In glmer(ex.drywght ~ forestloss562 * forestloss17 * roaddenssec *  :
>         calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly
>
> 2: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling

I then perform these subsequent steps (following the sequence of steps described in Grueber et al. (2011):

I standardize predictors,

```
stdz.model <- standardize(global.model, standardize.y = FALSE)
```

(requires package `arm`)

use automated model selection with subsets of the supplied ‘global’ model

```
model.set <- dredge(stdz.model)
```

requires package (`MuMIn`)

Here I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In dredge(stdz.model2) : comparing models fitted by REML
```

find the top 2 AIC models and

```
top.models <- get.models(model.set, subset = delta < 2)
```

do model averaging

```
model.avg(model.set, subset = delta < 2)
```

Here, I get this error message:

```
Error in apply(apply(z, 2L, is.na), 2, all) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Any advice on how to possibly fix this error would be very much appreciated.

In the second model, the response variable is richness, family is poisson.

```
global.model <- glmer(ex.richness ~ forestloss562*forestloss17*roaddenssec*nearestroadprim + 
                        elevation + soilPC1 + soilPC2 +
                       (1|block/fragment), 
                     data = mydata, 
                     family = "poisson")
```

When I execute the above command I get the following error and warning messages:

> Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
>
> 2: In pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tolPwrss, GQmat, compDev, fac, verbose) :
>         Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file:../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431
>
> 3: In pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tolPwrss, GQmat, compDev, fac, verbose) :
>         Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file:../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431

Please find a reproducible subset of my data below:

```
    structure(list(plot.code = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L), .Label = c("a100m56r", "b1m177r", "c100m56r", "d1f1r", "e1m177r", 
"f1m17r", "lf10m56r"), class = "factor"), site.code = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("a100m56", "b1m177", "c100m56", 
"d1f1", "e1m177", "f1m17", "lf10m56"), class = "factor"), block = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"f", "lf"), class = "factor"), fragment = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("a100", "b1", "c100", "d1", "e1", 
"f1", "lf10"), class = "factor"), elevation = c(309L, 342L, 435L, 
495L, 443L, 465L, 421L), forestloss562 = c(25.9, 56.77, 5.32, 
27.4, 24.25, 3.09, 8.06), forestloss17 = c(7.47, 51.93, 79.76, 
70.41, 80.55, 0, 0), roaddenssec = c(2.99, 3.92, 2.61, 1.58, 
1.49, 1.12, 1.16), nearestroadprim = c(438L, 237L, 2637L, 327L, 
655L, 528L, 2473L), soilPC1 = c(0.31, -0.08, 1.67, 2.39, -1.33, 
-1.84, -0.25), soilPC2 = c(0.4, 0.41, -0.16, 0.15, 0.03, -0.73, 
0.51), ex.richness = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ex.drywght = c(0, 
0, 1.255, 200.2825, 0, 0, 0.04)), .Names = c("plot.code", "site.code", 
"block", "fragment", "elevation", "forestloss562", "forestloss17", 
"roaddenssec", "nearestroadprim", "soilPC1", "soilPC2", "ex.richness", 
"ex.drywght"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: The kind of error messages you got for your first model normally indicates that your data is insufficient or ill-conditioned for supporting the models you are trying to fit. The second error probably occurs when you use `dredge`. Are all packages up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, the packages are up-to-date. Both error messages occur after executing the glmer command.

Comment: Well, you don't show the command taht results in the second error ...

Comment: Added the second model command. Many thanks.

Comment: You need to show exactly which commands you run and after which command exactly the error occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** you need to standardize your variables *before* you fit the model, for greater numerical stability.  I also have a few comments about the advisability of what you're doing, but I'll save them for the end ...

```
source("SO_glmer_26904580_data.R")
library("arm")
library("lme4")
library("MuMIn")
```

Try the first fit:

```
pmod <- glmer(ex.richness ~
              forestloss562*forestloss17*roaddenssec*nearestroadprim + 
                  elevation + soilPC1 + soilPC2 +
                      (1|block/fragment), 
              data = dat, 
              family = "poisson")
```

This fails, as reported above.
However, I get a warning you didn't report above:

```
## 1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

which provides a clue.

Scaling numeric parameters:

```
pvars <- c("forestloss562","forestloss17",
           "roaddenssec","nearestroadprim",
           "elevation","soilPC1","soilPC2")
datsc <- dat
datsc[pvars] <- lapply(datsc[pvars],scale)
```

Try again:

```
pmod <- glmer(ex.richness ~
              forestloss562*forestloss17*roaddenssec*nearestroadprim + 
                  elevation + soilPC1 + soilPC2 +
                      (1|block/fragment), 
              data = datsc, 
              family = "poisson",
              na.action="na.fail")
```

This works, although we get a warning message about a too-large gradient -- I think this is actually ignorable (we're still working on getting these error sensitivity thresholds right).

As far as I can tell, the following lines seem to be working:

```
stdz.model <- standardize(pmod, standardize.y = FALSE)
## increases max gradient -- larger warning
model.set <- dredge(stdz.model)  ## slow, but running ...
```

Here are my comments about advisability:

- Not even counting random-effects parameters, you have only 8x as many observations as predictor variables.  This is pushing it (a rule of thumb is that you should have 10-20 observations per parameter).

```
 nrow(datsc) ## 159
 ncol(getME(pmod,"X"))  ## 19
```

- Dredging/multi-model-averaging over models with and without interactions can be dangerous -- at the very least, centering continuous variables is necessary in order for it to be interpretable.  (I don't know whether `dredge` does anything to try to be sensible in this case.)

I also tried `glmmLasso` on this problem -- it ended up shrinking away all of the fixed effect terms ...

```
library("glmmLasso")
datsc$bf <- interaction(datsc$block,datsc$fragment)
glmmLasso(ex.richness ~
          forestloss562+forestloss17+roaddenssec+nearestroadprim + 
              elevation + soilPC1 + soilPC2,
          rnd=list(block=~1,bf=~1),
              data = datsc, 
              family = poisson(),
          lambda=500)
```

Comment: That is very helpful advice indeed, thank you. Can the 'lapply(datsc[pvars],scale' function be adjusted to use 2SD (unless this is the default already)? Also, I continue to get the different error message for the second model that uses biomass weight as a response variable, any additional advice on that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: something like `scale2 <- function(x) scale(x,scale=2*sd(x))` and then use `scale2` rather than `scale` in the `lapply`.  I will look at the second example if I get a chance.

Comment: seems like the error message was due to a single model being < 2 AIC, so no model averaging performed, thanks a lot

Comment: +1. "`glmmLasso` shrinks away all of the fixed effect terms" may be because the tuning parameter `lambda` is pretty large (500) here.